# tinymce toolbar

Tags: tinymce, toolbar

How can I do Tinymce toolbar draggable with jQuery?

Comment: please explain a little bit more abaot what you would like to achieve

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your tinyMCE init method

```
tinyMCE.init({
// ...
handle_event_callback : function(e) {
      if(e.type == 'click') {
           $('.mceExternalToolbar').draggable();
      }
      return true;
}
});
```

Include the following jQuery UI files :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

Note that i've tried this only with one tinyMCE instance.
I don't know if there are some side effects of this workaround, but it's working for now.